# Send remote linux command with 2 ssh via bastion

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to send a command to my machine which is on private cloud. for that I need to connect to bastion server and then to the private machine. my terminal -> bastion server -> target vm

I trying to use this command:
`ssh -i pem_key.pem vmuser@10.000.00.00 'touch test.txt' -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p bastionuser@160.000.000.00 -i pem_key.pem -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null"`

And I Get "Connection timed out" error.

Note, If I remove the 'touch test.txt' it will connect me to target vm. but I need a single command that I can use to send commands to my target VM.

Thanx

Comment: The general convention is to specify options *before* arbitrary operand(s), although in some cases some tools may be somewhat liberal. What if you supply `'touch test.txt'` *at the very end*?

Comment: that exactly worked! thanx.

Answer (score 0):

As Answered above the solution is:

`ssh -i pem_key.pem vmuser@10.000.00.00 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p bastionuser@160.000.000.00 -i pem_key.pem -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" 'touch test.txt'`

which is moving the 'command' ('touch test.txt') to the end.